# Autodesk Forge design automation [workitems request] fail in heroku deployment "Failed to create a workitem"

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I've downloaded the Design automation sample from github https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/tree/nodejs

I followed the toturial to make it working locally,
my issue is after deploying the app to heroku and filled the secret data, every thing is working correctly except for the workitems request it fails with code 500 Internal Server Error and response:
{"diagnostic":"Failed to create a workitem"}

[error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tOrA.png)

the error log file: https://mega.nz/file/b2Y3wTJD#FqyWubUvewk175j_Y75TfpwfkzZHNXhSH1Tt5NY4HPc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update FORGE_WEBHOOK_URL to https://test-f-daa.herokuapp.com on Heroku as well,  from the error log -
`{"url":["Failed to create URL for 'undefined/api/forge/callback/designautomation?....`

Comment: thanks that worked for the workitem request,
now I got another issue,
after creating the workitem then everything will not change, nothing will happen after that
here is my log for this issue:
https://mega.nz/file/37gFXKiQ#dJflQxaktl_swvzKFjLgtGQKnKklNb5Sgi7OAVlB0WQ

screenshoot:
https://mega.nz/file/WuhFjLpY#kAPs83t2mmfpRwoDt_OLuNcRHiOTxVeWXA_DgEUWKqE

Comment: Oh after resetting the secret data again, it worked! thanks a lot that saved a lot of time as I tried a lot in .net sample with no result, Thanks